# Kubernetes on Oracle Linux

Tags: kubernetes

Can somebody give me a starting point to install Kubernetes on Oracle Linux platform. I like to start some comparison between the orchestration of docker containers.

Regards
Walter

Answer (score 0):

You can use kubeadm for the cluster setup. I haven't worked with Oracle Linux. as long as it supports rpm & yam. you can install the kubernets software.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this guide from Bitnami to prepare a Kubernetes cluster in Oracle Cloud: https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/set-kubernetes-cluster-oracle/

The guide is meant for the Ubuntu image, but just as @sfgroups said, using `kubeadm` the process should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have established a kubernetes cluster on Oracle Linux 7.4 using Oracle VirtualBox and vagrant.

Github repo can be found https://github.com/bjarteb/ol-kubeadm

You need an oracle account to follow along (it's free)

[Oracle® Container Services for use with Kubernetes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E88884/html/index.html)

*vagrant up && vagrant ssh m* - and you are ready for *k8s*!

```
[vagrant@m ~]$ kubectl get nodes -owide
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION            EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                  KERNEL-VERSION                   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
m         Ready     master    1h        v1.8.4+2.0.1.el7   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 7.4   4.1.12-112.14.13.el7uek.x86_64   docker://17.12.0-ol
w1        Ready     <none>    1h        v1.8.4+2.0.1.el7   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 7.4   4.1.12-112.14.13.el7uek.x86_64   docker://17.12.0-ol
w2        Ready     <none>    57m       v1.8.4+2.0.1.el7   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 7.4   4.1.12-112.14.13.el7uek.x86_64   docker://17.12.0-ol
```